# Help with variables in htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

redirect http://**anySubdomain(wildcard)**.mydomain.com/

to:

**anysubdomain(wildcard)**.mydomain.com/page2.php

i tried with this:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/$1\.mydomain\.com\/page2\.php" [R=301,L]
```

But it does not work, the rewriteCond part works well, because, ANY subdomain is redirected.

But it reaches: " .mydomain.com/page2.php", what makes me think the problem is in the second line

Can you help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page2.php [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteRule only takes the URL-path (the part after the domain name) for the regex input. Sounds like you want every page to redirect to page2.php, which is what this does.